# Python discord Bot coping messages from one user and sending them in a webhook

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, webhooks

So I tried writting a bot that will copy messages from one user and send them in a webhook to a different server but I got stuck on coping the message and can't find any answers.

```
    import discord
    import os
    import requests
    import json
    from dhooks import Webhook, file
    
    
    hook = Webhook("WEBHOOK HERE")
    
    
    client = discord.Client()
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    
    
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.author.id == "ID HERE":
        hook.send(content = "MESSAGE HERE", username = "Secound", avatar_url = "https://i.imgur.com/Kg5IIib.png")
    
       
    
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.Message` has the attribute `content` that refers to the content of the message

```py
content = message.content
# i.e `Hello world`
```

#### Reference:

- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20content#discord.Message.content)